# High CPU Usage - Android Emulator (qemu-system-x86)

Tags: dual-boot, android, performance, android-studio, android-emulator

Distro - Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64
System Specs -
RAM: 8G
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Radeon V
GPU: AMD ATI 05:00.0 Picasso
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile

Running only android studio works just fine but when i try to just open my firefox it becomes too much for the system and it makes the whole system slow like can't even open my terminal. I have to press and hold my power button to shutdown and reboot.

[image]

top
You can see here the %CPU is 600.3 which is insane!!!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `free -m`? Knowing a bit more about your system memory information will help 

Comment: @matigo now good?

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem. Add a dedicated swap file or partition of 2x ram.

In my case was solved by adding 16G of swap and later I bought more ram.

try...

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1MiB count=$((16*1024))
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
```

then add a line to /etc/fstab like this

```
/swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
```

try it.
regards.

Comment: I am getting this error - swapon: /swapfile: swapon failed: Invalid argument